# Add session destroy event on Spring-Session with Redis

Tags: redis, spring-session

Does anybody know how to add a session destroy event in Spring Session with Redis?, I read that the normal way isn´t possible. I would like to do this because I need to do some cleaning process after a session is destroyed(timeout or logout).
I would really appreciate your help, thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RedisOperationsSessionRepository` will publish `org.springframework.session.events.SessionDestroyedEvent` (or to be more exact, its subclasses `SessionDeletedEvent` and `SessionExpiredEvent`) if it's configured with an `ApplicationEventPublisher`. This will happen automatically if you're using `@EnableRedisHttpSession` configuration support.

These events will then in turn be translated into `javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent` and then forwarded to all `HttpSessionListener`s, assuming they are registered with your application context as beans.

For more details refer to [HttpSessionListener
section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#httpsession-httpsessionlistener) of Spring Session's reference manual.

Answer (score 0):

For **spring boot 3+**

Change **`@EnableRedisHttpSession`** to --->**`@EnableRedisIndexedHttpSession`**.
This change will configure **RedisIndexedSessionRepository** over **RedisSessionRepository** .

By using this `RedisIndexedSessionRepository` you can now start to listen to `SessionCreatedEvent`, `SessionDeletedEvent`, `SessionDestroyedEvent` and `SessionExpiredEvent` events.

For detailed explanation visit [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/configuration/redis.html#configuring-redisindexedsessionrepository).
For listening to Session Events visit [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/reference/configuration/redis.html#listening-session-events).